# Cannot build Linphone android with different package name

Tags: android, linux, sdk, android-ndk, linphone

I am trying to build Linphone android from [this](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/README.md), with SDK api 23 and NDK r11c on Ubuntu 16.10. I already built it successfully but I cannot change its package name so as to be able to upload it to Google Play Store despite following its instruction to the letter. For Example:

> To create an apk with a different package name
>
> You need to edit the custom_rules.xml file:
>
> look for the property named "linphone.package.name" and change it value accordingly

Already done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules">
    <property name="linphone.package.name" value="my.name" />
....
```

Then I did this

> also update the values in the AndroidManifest file where the comment appears

by replacing all instances of `org.linphone` in every `<!-- Change package ! -->` comment. All of them are comments though so that may be not important. I did not change this one because it will throw an error when I run `make`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.linphone"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        android:versionCode="3253"
        android:versionName="3.2.5">
```

And the next step is

> change the package name also in the files: res/xml/syncadapter.xml, res/xml/contacts.xml and res/values/non_localizable_custom where appears

which I did exactly like I was told. The last step is running make.

But the result I always get is org.linphone no matter whichever name I changed  it to. Did I botched any step? Can we even change linphone package name to something other than `org.linphone`? And no, I cannot change its package name by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package), it would just brick the project, render it unbuildable.

Answer (score 1):

Now the package name are in build.gradle and no more in custom_rules.xml

```
def getPackageName() {
  return "org.linphone"
}
```

and its used here:

```
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    applicationId getPackageName()
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```